# Is this really the MVC design pattern or should I call it something else?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, router

This is a question about theory, so there is no need for code snippets.

I built a router that, as a typical router does, dispatches a controller based on the URL. The workflow is something like this:

1. Router dispatches controller and instantiates it
2. Controller renders a view
3. User interacts with the view
4. Controller updates model based on user interaction
5. Model returns the new state of the data to the controller
6. Controller updates the view based on new data

So basically, the controller is the starting point and the link between the model and view. The model and view never directly interact with each other. The controller is the workhorse and has most of the code.

Now, that is all good and I get it. The confusion comes when I read articles about MVC design patterns and realize what they describe is not what I just described above. It seems like, in the pattern you start at the view. The view talks directly to the model and the controller accepts user interaction to update the model.

So, what I'm doing may involve models, views and controllers, but its not strictly the MVC design pattern. I did read one article where they called what I first described as CAV, controller action view.

My question is, what is it that I'm describing? I don't want to keep referring to it as MVC if its not actually MVC. From what I read true MVC was birthed in the 70's. Things have changed since then. Perhaps what I'm doing is some evolved version of MVC, but not MVC in its strict form. Is there another name for it so I can stop confusing myself, and others, by calling it MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its language (technology) dependent.
You tagged your question with the **php** tag, so I suppose you're developing applications using this language. In a classic PHP application, the view can't get updates from the model (in fact, this more related to the PHP language being executed only on the server).

First, **the entire application is launched for each request** and is terminated when all the response has been sent. So, the router is called for each request.

Then, the router execute the controller which have to handle the request (according to routing rules).

The request being for reading or writing does not modify this behavior.

If you want to **allow the view to ask for data modification approval** to your controller, you may need to use some **client-side programming language** (Javascript). So, you may use a **REST API** to handle communication between the model and the view.

**To answer your question**, I think you can't implements a *pure* MVC design pattern on a client-server model without using a programming language on the client.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think the term MVC is probably used too loosely. I'm guilty of it as well. I supposed my application is in an MVC style, but not true MVC. That causes confusion when asking questions or doing research and different people and places have different interpretations of MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this confusion previously. In the original form, View did interact with the controller. They followed the observer-observable pattern. This was how MVC was conceived in SmallTalk. However, The version of MVC that you are talking about is actually a modern version of it and is used in most frameworks. It sort of has became a standard. I do not know of any other term for it. In this version, the controller is actually a bridge between view and model. However, both of the patterns achieve the desired objective of separation of concerns.

Comment: Yep, I suppose whatever you call it isn't as important as if it achieves your goal. Thanks!